# How to rollback after save model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this code using ruby on rails 3.2

```
def craete
  @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      @account = Account.where(name: params[:name]).first
      @tenant = Tenant.new()
      @tenant.name = @account.name
      @tenant.account_id = @account.id          
      if !@tenant.save
        raise ApiError.new(ApiError::VALIDATION, @tenant.errors, 1103, :unprocessable_entity)
      end
      audit('Admin.Account.Create', account_params)
      @success = ApiSuccess.new(@account, 1210, request.method, false, 'Account created')
      render '/api_success', status: :created
    else
      raise ApiError.new(ApiError::VALIDATION, @account.errors, 1103, :unprocessable_entity)
    end
end
```

My question is that how can we rollback account if tenant can't save ?

thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). save both account and tenant under transaction block. If any one of them failed whole transaction would be rolled back

```
@account.transaction do 
  if @account.save
   @account = Account.where(name: params[:name]).first
   @tenant = Tenant.new()
   @tenant.name = @account.name
   @tenant.account_id = @account.id          
   if !@tenant.save
     raise ApiError.new(ApiError::VALIDATION, @tenant.errors, 1103, :unprocessable_entity)
   end
   audit('Admin.Account.Create', account_params)
   success = ApiSuccess.new(@account, 1210, request.method, false, 'Account created')
   render '/api_success', status: :created
 else
  raise ApiError.new(ApiError::VALIDATION, @account.errors, 1103, :unprocessable_entity)
 end
```

end

Comment: {"social.audit":{"auditable_type":"Admin.Account.Create","customer_id":1,"audited_changes":{"name":"test","email":"test@yahoo.com"},"created_at":"2014-07-26T18:26:29+07:00","action":"Admin.Account.Create"}} was returned! reply_code = 312, reply_text = NO_ROUTE, 
It can not save event I input right data ?